# A little misunderstanding with constructors syntax

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm starting learn constructors and destructors in C++ and I saw it

```
Vector(const Vector& V) {x=V.x;y=V.y;}
```

and

`Vector(const Vector& V) : x(V.x), y(V.y) {}`

But I can't understand what is the second one, this

`Vector(const Vector& V) {x=V.x; y=V.y;}`

that I suppose equals to

```
Vector(const Vector& V) {
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
}
```

But what is the other one equals?

Comment: i know that first is constructor without initializing and second with it

Comment: `Vector(const Vector&V):x(V.x),y(V.y){}` is a copy constructor, which initializes the x and y member variables.  `Vector(const Vector&V) {x=V.x;y=V.y;}` is a copy constructor, which looks like it does not initialize the x and y member variables (unless they have default initializations), and then assigns values to them.  In general, initializing the member variables is recommended, rather than assigning.  With optimizations enabled, they're probably the same (but **profile** to make sure).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Where are you learning about constructors that hasn't told you what the second one means? It cannot be a good tutorial.